# Measure the length of a string literal that contains unicode character representations?

Tags: r

```
nchar("\u058f")
[1] 1
```

came as a surprise to me (I expected either 6 or 4).

#### Question

How can we measure the number of literal characters in a string containing unicode representations of the form `\uxxxx`?

#### What I tried so far

I tried tinkering with different `types`, but

```
> nchar("\u058f", type = "bytes")
[1] 2
> nchar("\u058f", type = "chars")
[1] 1
> nchar("\u058f", type = "width")
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the Unicode characters, which can be done by for example the [stringi](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/index.html) function `stri_escape_unicode`:

```
nchar(stringi::stri_escape_unicode("\u058f"))

# [1] 6
```